# Search and replace substring according to regex

Tags: javascript

I have a string something like this:

```
var str = 'Foo faa {{as56asdjhw76234564}} {{ehksfd1238548dsah}}'
```

I need to replace the text between braces by some substring which will result in something like:

```
Foo faa {{Question 1}} {{Question 22}}
```

But, my problem is how do I search for this substring? Inside the braces there can be only digits and alphabets.

Comment: Where are you stuck? To match `{{something}}`, you use a regexp of the form `/{{something}}/`. If something is a sequence of alphanumber characters, you can write `[a-z0-9]+`, or `\w+` if you don't mind including underscores. To make the regexp case-insensitive, and global, you add the flags `ig`. To replace the regexp, you use `String#replace`. This is just basic regexp writing that would be covered in any beginning regexp tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method with regex [`/{{[a-z0-9]+}}/ig`](https://regex101.com/r/rF1pT0/2) for matching the pattern and replacing.

```js
var str = 'Foo faa {{as56asdjhw76234564}} {{ehksfd1238548dsah}}',
  rep = [1, 22],
  i = 0;

console.log(
  str.replace(/{{[a-z0-9]+}}/ig, function() {
    return '{{Question ' + rep[i++] + '}}'
  })
)
```

Comment: @torazaburo : to get smallest possible match... otherwise `{{as56asdjhw76234564}} {{ehksfd1238548dsah}}` will get matched, check here https://regex101.com/r/rF1pT0/1

Comment: No, it won't, because the intervening characters do not match `[a-z0-9]`.

Comment: @torazaburo : oops you are ,,,, initially the regex were `/{{.+?}}/`...... updated now and thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regexp:

```
\{{2}([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\}{2}
```

You can then use the `replace` method with a callback argument, like:

```
let questionIndex = 0;
myString.replace(/\{{2}([a-z0-9]+)\}{2}/gmi, 
  function (fullExpression, matchedGroup1) {
    // NOTE fullExpression is {{abc} for example
    //      matchedGroup1 is the 'abc' itself

    questionIndex++;

    return `{{Question ${questionIndex}}}`;
  }
);
```

See the example below:

https://jsfiddle.net/xb3q63y9/

Also, for Regexp, there's this useful tool called Regex101, really helpful when you need a specific string to be matched:

https://regex101.com/r/sK7qZ0/2

Comment: Minor point perhaps, but he doesn't want Question 1 and Question 2, he wants Question 1 and Question 22, where 1 and 22 presumably come from some list of replacement question numbers. Also, why the `m` flag?